# How can I add href to my button on SharePoint

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I create some buttons with css style and now I need to add href to all of them. I tried use JavaScript, with add tag `<form action="href">` change `<button>` on `<input>`, tried with CSS and `<button onclick="href">`,  but this still no work.

This is my HTML one of the button

```
<th> 
        <button class="img" type="button8"> 
           <p class="single">​ HR 
              <br/> </p></button>​​​ </th>
```

and this css style

```
[type=button8] {
            margin-top: 5px;
            marring-left: 5px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            width: 260px; 
            height: 155px;
            background: url('https://share.novartis.net/sites/ruphoncology/Shared%20Documents/00778_300dpi_RGB.jpg');
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            text-color: black; }
```

I need, when user click on button, he is transferred it to another page.
P.S This is all on SharePoint Online with WebPart Editor

Comment: did you tried with anchor tag <a>...</a> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a this onclick attribute to ur button:

```html
<button onclick="location.href='https://www.google.com/';">Click</button>
```

Or use Javascript to add the attribute of the button:

```js
document.getElementById('my_button').setAttribute("onclick", "location.href='https://www.google.com/';");
```

If u use the form tag u can submit while change ur button attribute like this:

```js
document.getElementById('my_button').setAttribute("onclick", "document.getElementById('my_form').action = 'https://google.com/'; document.getElementById('my_form').submit();");
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using designer/content editor
https://www.url.com/';">Button